# THREE.js: making a skinned mesh follow a spline

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I have a skinned mesh of a 'snake', exported from blender.
The snake has bones (like a spine) which I want to animate along a curve (SplineCurve3)

I can calculate points along the spline, and the angles between those points, but I'm struggling setting the rotations of the bones correctly.

The problem is that each bone is a child of the previous bone, so rotating one also rotates the others.

Here's an image:

[image: problem]

The outer shape is the snake.

The pink line is a section of a SplineCurve3.

The blue/green lines are the bones (THREE.SkeletonHelper).

Each bone is rotated using SplineCurve3.getTangentAt. Because the parent is rotated too, the snake curls up. I basically need the bones to be where the pink line is.

How can I 'compensate' for the rotation of the parent(s) when calculating the rotation of a bone?

Also, in the image the path is flat, but my goal is to move the snake in 3 dimensions. It's a flying snake.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify which rotation is which (maybe draw some angles and label them for reference)?

If the whole snake is at an angle to the axes, then just subtract that angle from the bone angle.

Surely, however, the bone angles are defined relative to the parent bone, not as absolute angles against the axes? If you are using the absolute angles subtended with the x-axis as relative angles, then that would produce the behaviour you see of increasingly rotated bones.

Assuming the bone angles should be given relative to the parent bone, then you want:

```
childRelativeAngle = childAbsoluteAngle - parentAbsoluteAngle
```